# Replace NULL with average of previous and next record

Tags: sql, replace, null, calculated-columns

(Newbie working in Access).

I have some data which is PV output in kW given one hourly.
The data has an empty cell on each half hour and I would like to create a column that contains the average of the Xpm and Ypm values in the empty X.30 pm record.

INPUT DATA ((PV_KW): my data looks like this:

```
1pm,    30kW;
1.30pm, NULL;
2pm,    40kW;
2.30pm  NULL;
3pm,    60kW;
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: I want this to become

```
1pm,    30kW;
1.30pm, 35kW;
2pm,    40kW;
2.30pm, 50KW;
3pm,    60kW;
```

The query I have written does the average ok, but the output column (PV_KW_AVG) contains ONLY the average and replaces my original data with NULLs... i.e. I am getting this:

```
1pm,    NULL;
1.30pm, 35kW;
2pm,    NULL;
2.30pm, 50KW;
3pm,    NULL;
```

Here's my query:

```
    SELECT 

    (
    (SELECT last(PV_kw)
       FROM PV_and_load AS temp
      WHERE PV_and_load.id =(temp.id+1) 
            AND temp.PV_kw IS NOT NULL)
    +
    (SELECT last(PV_kw)
       FROM PV_and_load AS temp2
      WHERE PV_and_load.id = (temp2.id-1) 
            AND temp2.PV_kw IS NOT NULL)
    )
    /2

AS PV_KW_avg, *
FROM PV_and_load;
```

Can anyone tell how to make the output into my desired output - i.e. calculate the average AND keep the original data?

Comment: @Hamidreza appears to be Access

Comment: Did you try using `COALESCE`? Like that: `COALESCE(PV_kw, (((SELECT last(PV_kw) FROM PV_and_load AS temp WHERE PV_and_load.id =(temp.id+1) AND temp.PV_kw IS NOT NULL) + (SELECT last(PV_kw) FROM PV_and_load AS temp2 WHERE PV_and_load.id = (temp2.id-1) AND temp2.PV_kw IS NOT NULL)) /2)`

Comment: I just saw that access doesnt have the Coalesce function. Use `Nz` instead

Comment: Thanks Hamidreza - haven't been able to get Nz to work (Access says "Invalid SQL statement", but that may be the format of the query)- will keep trying...

Answer (score 0):

if your query works fine then you can do something like this:

```
SELECT ID,CASE WHEN PV_kw IS NOT NULL THEN PV_kw ELSE PV_KW_avg AS PV_KW FROM
(SELECT
(
(SELECT last(PV_kw)
   FROM PV_and_load AS temp
  WHERE PV_and_load.id =(temp.id+1) 
        AND temp.PV_kw IS NOT NULL)
+
(SELECT last(PV_kw)
   FROM PV_and_load AS temp2
  WHERE PV_and_load.id = (temp2.id-1) 
        AND temp2.PV_kw IS NOT NULL)
)
/2
AS PV_KW_avg, *
FROM PV_and_load) tab;
```

Comment: Thanks again... I'm getting a missing operator error with that query - but I'll see if I can decode where that's coming from.